# Is it possible to mix map arguments in Azure Pipelines template yaml? How?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I wonder if it is possible to mix map arguments in Azure Pipelines template yaml, and how to do it.

These two scenarios shown bellow do same thing: place template parameter as env argument in a task, but in the second I'm trying to do it through two maps instead of a single one. That could be useful when I have different purposes to those values (at the eyes of someone who is extending the template) but both are going to be used as 'env' under the hood.

**This works fine:**

Main Pipeline:

```
...

extends:
  template: templates/deploy/v1/deployment.job.yaml@infrastructure-templates
  parameters:
    name: dev
    variableGroup: 'AzureDevopsVariableGroupName'
    secretEnvVariables:
      SECRET1: ${SECRET1}       
      SECRET2: ${SECRET2}
```

Target Template:

```
parameters:
- name: secretEnvVariables
  type: object
jobs:
    ...
    steps:          
    - bash: |
        #!/bin/bash

        echo "SECRET1 = ${SECRET1}"
        ...              
      displayName: Substitute Env VARS on files
      enabled: true
      env: 
        ${{ parameters.secretEnvVariables }}
```

**This doesn't work (and I wonder if it is possible to make it work):**

Main Pipeline:

```
...

extends:
  template: templates/deploy/v1/deployment.job.yaml@infrastructure-templates
  parameters:
    name: dev
    variableGroup: 'AzureDevopsVariableGroupName'
    secretEnvVariables:
      SECRET1: ${SECRET1}       
      SECRET2: ${SECRET2}
    moreVariables:
      VAR1: ${VAR1}
```

Target Template:

```
parameters:
- name: secretEnvVariables
  type: object
- name: moreVariables
  type: object
jobs:
    ...
    steps:          
    - bash: |
        #!/bin/bash

        echo "SECRET1 = ${SECRET1}"
        echo "VAR = ${VAR1}"
        ...              
      displayName: Substitute Env VARS on files
      enabled: true
      env: 
        ${{ parameters.secretEnvVariables }} 
        ${{ parameters.moreVariables }}
```

Can it be done? How to do it?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am doing something similar and this isn't well documented but can use objects to accomodate for this.

Here it is the combo of environment and region deployment:

```
- name: environmentObjects
  type: object
  default: 
  - environmentName: 'dev'
    regionAbrvs: ['eus']
  - environmentName: 'uat'
    regionAbrvs: ['eus', 'cus']
```

From there it would be a loop to access each one like:

```
- ${{ each environmentObject in parameters.environmentObjects }} :
  - ${{ each regionAbrv in enviornmentObject.regionAbrvs }} :
```

This should work for your scenario as well.